# How to download twitter data using python for a given twitter url?

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

How to download twitter data using python for a given twitter url?  For example - twitter.com/1/statuses/1264692679029522434

but I am quite new to this world, Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the docs for tweepy: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/